# Summing up discrete probabilities - trivial?

Tags: summation, random-variables, index-notation

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^i p_X(i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i p_X(i).
$$
This is from a problem solution in introductory probability theory course (problem 3a [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-i/lecture-4/MIT6_041SCF13_assn03.pdf), solution [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-i/lecture-4/MIT6_041SCF13_assn03_sol.pdf))  . X is a random variable that takes nonnegative integer values. The expression implies that sum from 1 to i of probabilities of X being i is equal to i (inner sum collapses into i). But I'm not sure why that is the case.

I understand that 1) probabilities for ALL i's must add up to 1, and 2) if we take 1 i times (the summation) we should get i. But it doesn't connect... Perhaps not fully getting notation here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note the following two things: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^i 1 = i$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^i \alpha f(k)=\alpha \sum\limits_{k=1}^i f(k)$ where $\alpha$ is a constant with respect to $k$.  Now, recognize that $p_X(i)$ is a constant with respect to $k$.  If notation is what is causing the issue, recognize that nested summations can be evaluated inside-out, that is to say the first summation is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^i p_X(i)\right)$

Comment: Rereading your question, "*the expresion implies that sum from $1$ to $i$ of probabilities of $X$ being $i$ is equal to $i$*"  This isn't correct.  The sum from $1$ to $i$ of probabilities of $X$ being $i$ is equal to $i$ **times the probability of $X$ being $i$**.  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^ip_X(i)=(ip_X(i))$

Comment: That's awesome. I was trying to get intuitive understanding and couldn't... but it makes sense when done analytically step by step like you did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about probabilities adding up to $1.$ Suppose, for example, that $i=4.$ Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^i p_X(i) = \sum_{k=1}^4 p_X(4) = \underset{\Large\underset{k=1}\uparrow}{p_X(4)} + \underset{\Large\underset{k=2}\uparrow}{p_X(4)} + \underset{\Large\underset{k=3}\uparrow}{p_X(4)} + \underset{\Large\underset{k=4}\uparrow}{p_X(4)} = 4p_X(4) = ip_X(i).
$$

Note that in the expression $p_X(i),$ the index $k$ that goes from $1$ to $4$ does not appear. That is why all four terms are the same as each other.